# OSX: Remap Caps Lock as a modifier key likey cmd

Tags: keyboard

The standard layout on an a macbook pro is not quite efficient if one wants to do a lot of programming. I want to change that with some small tweaks. 
One of those would be: Change Caps Lock to be a key like cmd and ctrl. For example if I want to write '{' I want to press 'Caps + a'.

Is that possible?